# Is it possible to compile a C# program to run on an Android phone?

Tags: c#, android

I have some basic code made in C#. Is it possible to compile it for Android with little to no code changes?

Comment: using http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid you can run C# code into Android app

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, you can develop application for android!

1. [Xamarin For Android](http://android.xamarin.com/)  - Not a free product, full functional trial is available.
2. [Dot42](http://www.dot42.com/) - Not free for commercial use.

You can use them!

Comment: It looks like the free version of Dot42 does not allow commercial use, so I don't know if I'd call it 100% free.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use something like [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) (formerly MonoTouch).